# Database operations needed for the required output

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables and have to combined to get the required dataset as follows.
Some pointers towards the required database operations would be highly appreciated.

Table 1

```
EBELN   EBELP   EKORG

4500020014  10  100
4500020014  20  100
4500020015  10  100
0       0       0       
4500020016  10  100
```

table 2

```
EBELN           EBELP   BELNR

4500020014  10  1000000000
4500020014  20  1000000001
4500020015  10  1000000002
4500020015  10  1000000003
                1000000004
4500020016  10  0
```

Table 3

```
BELNR   NETPR

1000000000  119
1000000001  129
1000000002  139
1000000003  149
1000000004  159
```

Expected Resulting Table

```
EBELN   EBELP   EKORG   BELNR   NETPR

4500020014  10  100 1000000000  119
4500020014  20  100 1000000001  129
4500020015  10  100 1000000002  139
4500020015  10  100 1000000003  149
                    1000000004  159
4500020016  10  100     0
```

Comment: Please post what you have attempted so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query does the work

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Ebeln, t2.Ebelp, t1.Ekorg, t2.belnr, t3.netpr FROM TABLE1 t1
RIGHT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.EBELN = t2.EBELN
FULL JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.belnr = t3.belnr
```